# Protractor execution hangs

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I have the following code:

```
it('Should be able to sign in', function() {
    // Find page elements
    var userNameField = browser.findElement(By.id('email'));
    var userPassField = browser.findElement(By.id('password'));
    browser.sleep('1000');
    var userLoginBtn = browser.findElement(By.id('loginbtn'));

    // Fill input fields
    userNameField.sendKeys('abc');
    userPassField.sendKeys('123');

    // Ensure fields contain what we've entered
    expect(userNameField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('abc');
    expect(userPassField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('123');

    // Click to sign in
    userLoginBtn.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/user/dashboard');
});

it('Should be able to logout', function () {

    element(by.id('logout')).click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/login');
});
```

The problem is that it's not reaching the second 'it', but fails with:

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="logout"])
```

If I add:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Then it continues to the last test and it works, but is this the right solution ?

Comment: try increasing the time for `allScriptsTimeout` key to some higher value in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to disable angular since you are using browser.findElement(By.id('email')); I assume the page is not using Angular;

If you need to navigate to a page which does not use Angular, you can turn off waiting for Angular by setting `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)

[Timeouts](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts)